# Cmake can't find gcc compiler

Tags: software-installation, compiling, gcc, c++, cmake

I have Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS and I am trying to install and run gcc v8 (a v7 version is the default).

I have done:
sudo apt-get install build-essential

sudo apt-get install gcc-8

To try to get the v8 to be default I did:
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-7 700 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-7
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-8 800 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-8

If I run gcc -v I get:

Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-8 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.4.0 (Ubuntu 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04)

But running make all -j  I get:

git submodule init
git submodule update --init --recursive
mkdir -p build && cd build && cmake  ..
-- CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE: Release
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:42 (project):
The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

```
/usr/bin/c++
```

is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.

Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Another similar post recommended build-essential but I already have that - what do I need to do to fix it?

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: So did you try the suggested remedy of setting the CXX environment variable? ex. `export CXX=/usr/bin/g++-8` before running `make`

Comment: No I hadn't, I didn't know what to set it to - did as you suggested but g++-8 does not exist...

Comment: Did you install it? I assumed so since you apparently added it as a slave with update-alternatives. If you didn't, then please do so (`sudo apt install g++-8`)

Comment: gcc-7, g++-7 and gcc-8 exist but /usr/bin/g++-8 is not there - am I missing an install?

Comment: Likely yes - `g++-8` is a separate package, installing `gcc-8` on its own is not sufficient

Comment: Yes it was missing - installed it - still no joy! Same message...

Comment: Its looking for /usr/bin/c++ which is a link to /etc/alternatives/c++ which is a link to /usr/bin/g++ which doesn't exist...

Comment: Take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370061/i-am-using-ubuntu-20-04-lts-trying-to-get-from-gcc-9-4-to-gcc-10-or-higher/1370140#1370140 which has some suggestions for the equivalent gcc situation.

Comment: OK, @ubfan1, I looked at the post and re-ran update-alternatives and that has fixed it!

Comment: Many thanks to everyone, compiler found.